# Implementing a UISearchController in Swift Core Data Project

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm presently taking an iOS development course. As part of an assignment, I'm tasked with creating a `UISearchController` in a note tracking project using Core Data in Swift.

Every example I've found is in Objective-C or is filtering a static array. Apple's "sample" code, updated in December 2014 doesn't compile in Xcode 6.3.

To add a `UISearchController`, I've got **3 primary tasks to do:**

1) Create a view controller to present search results. I'm using a TableViewController.

2) Create a UISearchController, and pass it my search results view controller.

**What's "stumping" me is now to get a hold of the objects in the managedObjectsContext.** Prior to attempting to add a `UISearchController`, my app works fine. I can add, edit, and delete items. I'm using the "canned" Core Data code in Xcode 6.3 with the stack in AppDelegate.

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

    var searchController: UISearchController? = nil

func addSearchBar() {
    var resultsController = SearchResultsTableViewController()
    resultsController.notes = // stumped what to call the notes. Trying to call an array from the Notes class below
    resultsController.delegate = self

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    searchController!.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
    searchController!.searchBar.frame = CGRect(
        x: searchController!.searchBar.frame.origin.x,
        y: searchController!.searchBar.frame.origin.y, width: searchController!.searchBar.frame.size.width, height: 44.0)

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController!.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

3) The UISearchController will notify its searchResultsUpdater (a class that conforms to UISearchResultsUpdating) when the search text changes. I'm using my search results view controller implement this protocol so I can update the filtered results.

Below is my `Note: NSManagedObject` class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class Note: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var dateCreated: NSDate
@NSManaged var dateEdited: NSDate
@NSManaged var noteTitle: String
@NSManaged var noteBody: String

// TODO: adding this to make it easier to handle names
class func notes() -> NSArray {
    let whereMyNotesAreStored = // Need syntax for where my MyManagedObjectContext is located
    let dataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: whereMyNotesAreStored!)

    var notesArray = NSMutableArray()

    for dictionary in dataArray {
        var note = Note()
        note.noteTitle = dictionary["noteTitle"] as! String
        note.noteBody = dictionary["noteBody"] as! String
        note.dateCreated = dictionary["dateCreated"] as! String
        note.dateEdited = dictionary["dateEdited"] as! String

        notesArray.addObject(note)
    }

    return NSArray(array: notesArray as! [AnyObject])
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to setting the context:

**Calling back to the App Delegate:**, like this

```
    let appDelegate : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
```

or **passing the context forward** from the App Delegate to the Master View Controller, which then passes it on to any subsequent view controllers, etc.  Each view controller will need a property defined for the context; when a new VC is instantiated, the context is set before the VC is presented/pushed, eg:

```
    class CustomViewController : UIViewController {
        var managedObjectContext : NSManagedObjectContext
        ...
```

and, when loading a new view controller,

```
    let newVC = CustomViewController()
    newVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    ...
```

To access the objects, use either a `NSFetchRequest` or `NSFetchedResultsController` to create an array of results, which you can then pass to the resultsController.  eg. for a fetch request:

```
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Notes")
    var error : NSError? = nil
    let fetchedResults = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: &error)
```

(Your notes() function is on the wrong track - you would not use NSArray(contentsOfFile:) to access CoreData objects.  Also, you must use the designated initialiser for NSManagedObject subclasses: so not `var note = Notes()` but `var note = Notes(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext?)`

Comment: Thank you. I haven't got it all figured out yet, but this is very helpful. It feels like I'm the first person to implement a `UISearchController` in a Core Data project using Swift. I think I'm going to nuke my branch and start over again incorporating your suggestions.

In terms of "Steps", am I on the right path w/ the wrong syntax?

Comment: Yes, the steps in your question look good.  Which project template did you use?  I think the Master-Detail template works by passing the context forward from the App Delegate, and uses an NSFetchedResultsController to populate the primary table view.  I would start with that template and then incorporate the search controller.

Comment: Yep. I'm using a Master-Detail VC layout. I'm picking through [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Listings/TableSearch_swift_TableSearch_swift_MainTableViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014683-TableSearch_swift_TableSearch_swift_MainTableViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_21) (doesn't compile, punching it in "by hand") also references an array of "products". I'm thinking I still need to create an array of "Notes" contained within the managedObjectContext that I can call as a class method.